# Incorrect refresh token from fitbit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, fitbit

I am integrating fitbit in iOS app, my issue is - after login with `fitbit` account.

I am getting code and with that code getting refresh token and access token by using http request, But when I refresh that refresh-token value by http request I am getting error.

Error is as below.

```
"Refresh token invalid or expired:"
```

If any anyone have any idea regarding this issue then kindly help me out.

Thanks

Comment: This below link has sample code with fitbit framework [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393507/fitbit-framework-is-available/34393522#34393522